# Какая разница между методом enqueue() в LinkedQueue и методом push() в LinkedStack?

Tags: очередь, стек

Какая разница между методом enqueue() в LinkedQueue и методом push() в LinkedStack?

Comment: А где эти контейнеры определены?

Answer (score 2):

Делают они одно и тоже, по сути.

```
public void push (T element){
    LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T> (element);

    temp.setNext(top);
    top = temp;
    count++;
}

public void enqueue (T element){
      LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

      if (isEmpty())
         front = node;
      else
         rear.setNext (node);

      rear = node;
      count++;
}
```

Разница лишь в том, куда вставка происходит. Почему по-разному методы названы - загадка.

Comment: Потому что в очередь ставят - enqueue, А в стек традиционно кладут, помещают, запихивают - push. Для разных понятий разные глаголы, разные действия, чтобы бы показать саму суть происходящего, чтобы всё ясно было даже дураку.

Comment: @Sergey да вроде из названия класса ясно и так =\

Comment: На самом деле и классы энти не нужны. Это же всего лишь List, с копиями метода add, названого по-другому. Не нужны нам ни одинаковые методы, ни одинаковые классы. List#add наше всё!